Inserting or merging time-ordered records
I have a table containing weather information for various locations. Each location is identified by an identifier station_id, and each kind of information is identified by a string (e.g. wind_speed, humidity,...).
Here is a simplified example. first_time and last_time are two timestamps, I will explain later what they are for.



first_time
last_time
station_id
name
value




10:00
10:10
1
wind_speed
12


10:15
10:40
1
wind_speed
9


10:20
10:25
1
humidity
43


10:25
10:40
2
wind_speed
2


10:45
10:50
1
wind_speed
10



Each couple (station_id, name) defines a time series. If we focus on the couple (1, wind_speed), we see that it is measured every 5 minutes. At 10:00, 10:05, and 10:10 it has been measured to be 12 m/s (units are implicit), then from 10:15 to 10:40 it dropped to 9 m/s, then at 10:45 and 10:50 the measurement read 10.
The fact that not each measurement results in a new record is an optimization, which allows to keep the table dramatically smaller than it could be (some of these variables change very rarely or never at all). We keep two timestamps to identify the first timestamp where that property had a given value, and the last measurement when it did.
When we want to insert a new measurement result in a the table, we look at the last value present in the table with the same station ID and property name, and if its value differs, we add a new record. Otherwise we update the last_time of the record that exists already. We call this operation a "merge", even though it differs from the SQL MERGE query.
Here is the question: how do we perform this operation safely and efficiently? We currently perform two queries (a SELECT and an UPDATE or an INSERT). The operation we want to perform is similar to UPSERT, but not quite the same. The (station_id, name) index does not have any unique constraint. Is there any way to perform this operation in a single query in PostgreSQL?

Why not use MERGE?  The data source can be a VALUES statement.

If the meter reading for the (station_id, name) are the same as the latest one then just do nothing. Remove last_time column from the table completely. You can easily calculate it (maybe in a view?) using lead window function.

Please update your question to include sample new data and the expected results. Make sure to include an example of each case for both INSERT and UPDATE. All as text - no images.

FYI What you're doing here is known as the Entity Attribute Value (EAV) model.

I would try to make it a bit simpler. Assuming that last_time can be calculated later in a query using lead window function then you need not update or merge the latest record for (first_time, station_id, name) if the value is the same but skip the event instead. Here is a parameterized query:
insert into readings (first_time, station_id, "name", "value")
select :first_time, :station_id, :name, :value
where (
  select "value" from readings
  where first_time = :first_time 
    and station_id = :station_id
    and "name" = :name
  order by first_time desc limit 1
 ) <> :value;

I would also suggest that you remove column last_time from the table.
You will need the proper index (station_id, name, first_time) too.
A fiddle to experiment with

That way you lose the indication of how long it took for the change to occur. Keeping first/last tells OP that when humidity stays constant between yesterday and today then changes tomorrow, the change happened sometime between today and tomorrow. If humidity was constant for the entire year, without saving first+last you can't tell if subsequent change was sudden or things were heating/cooling slowly the entire time while the sensor kept quiet. That being said, I second the idea if OP doesn't need to know if a sensor was completely quiet/offline, or it kept reporting stable values.

@Zegarek I see your point. Yet It seems to me that there are two different concerns here. My preference would be for a separate watchdog service that monitors sensors' health and barks when it sniffs something wrong or suspicious. This might be a matter of personal taste too.


In a MERGE join condition suggested by @Adrian Klaver, you can add a subquery to only look for matches against the latest recod for a given station_id and name: demo at db<>fiddle
merge into measurements current
using (values ('today 10:56'::timestamp,'today 10:56'::timestamp,1,'wind_speed',10)
             ,('today 10:56'::timestamp,'today 10:56'::timestamp,1,'humidity',46) )
as incoming(first_time,last_time,station_id,name_,value_)
on ( (current.station_id,current.name_,current.value_)
    =(incoming.station_id,incoming.name_,incoming.value_)
  and current.ctid=(select ctid from measurements as m2
                    where (m2.station_id,m2.name_,m2.value_)
                         =(incoming.station_id,incoming.name_,incoming.value_)
                    order by last_time desc limit 1) )
when matched then update set
  last_time=incoming.last_time
when not matched then insert
  values (incoming.first_time,incoming.last_time,incoming.station_id,incoming.name_,incoming.value_);

That wind_speed is the same as the latest, so it gets merged. The humidity changed, so it's added as a separate entry. I'm using the built-in column ctid to uniquely identify the latest row.
It helps to index and possibly cluster the table - you definitely don't want to seq scan for the latest data on each insert.

Split the table in two: one for your already "compressed" history data and a separate one for current measurements, holding a unique row for each station_id and measurement name. This lets you insert...on conflict do update against the one with current data, since it requires the constraint. When you get the same value again, it just bumps up the last_time in current_measurements. A triger can see when a new, different value appears and move the old one to the history table, so that the new one takes its place as the current. To look at all measurements, you can set up a view that connects them with a union all:
create view all_measurements as 
  table history_measurements union all
  table current_measurements;

This setup simplifies the search for the latest entry - it's always in the small and easy to navigate table with all unique entries. The only index that's strictly required is the tiny unique on the current_measurements that guides the upsert.


